# Merging existing iPhone and iPad app ids into a single universal app id

Tags: ios, universal, app-id

I have an existing iPhone app and an iPad app, now I have created a Universal app, and I want to know if there is any way to kind of "merge" the existing app Ids, so I can upload my new app as an update for the previous ones.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure bundling app ID's will do what you want. Check out this thread re: bundle id's instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575552/can-i-change-the-bundle-identifier-in-my-app-after-its-been-approved.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you cannot merge the apps. You can upload the universal version  as the new version for the iphone as well as for the ipad, but then you'll need to manage them both separately which is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. I asked this question while at WWDC, of several Apple employees in the developer support group, and the answer is "not at this time, please file a bug report if this is a feature you'd like to see".

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the case, just wanted to see if anyone knew otherwise. I think I'll file that bug report =)

Comment: I confirmed with several Apple engineers that bug reports, _especially duplicates_ help drive features and engineering effort.