# Is there a way to merge an iPhone and an iPad app (available in the app store as separate apps) in to 1 universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging existing iPhone and iPad app ids into a single universal app id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470684/merging-existing-iphone-and-ipad-app-ids-into-a-single-universal-app-id)

I know how to make the project an universal binary and if def for the different devices my problem comes from the app store. Both of the apps are already available for sale.

-The apps are paid and I need to allow the users of the iPad to be able to download the iPhone version.
-or ideally i will be able to merge the two apps and be left with 1 app only.

-I know i could just delete one of the apps and make the other universal but what happens to the users who bought the other one.

-Also i know i could make both of the apps universal but in this way i duplicate app store content and i don't want to do that.

**Does anyone knows other solutions?**

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple. The answer is, no.
I'm affraid you will have to make that universal app.