# After converting iPhone app to Universal app, should I only remove iPad app from sale or are there better steps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

I had 2 separate apps, 1 for iPhone, 1 for iPad (not my idea, I wanted Universal from the beginning). I've already converted the iPhone to a Universal app so I don't need any help with that.

Now I'm wondering, do I remove pre-existing iPad app from sale in iTunesConnect. (I know how to do this as well) or is there another way that would allow users with iPad app downloaded to be alerted that a new, Universal app exists to download.

The way it is now, if I just remove iPad app from sale, they won't be able to redownload it, but they won't necessarily know there's a Universal version unless they look at list of apps by us or search for app by name.

I see that others have asked the same thing years ago and wonder if an update has changed anything:
[Merging existing iPhone and iPad app ids into a single universal app id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470684/merging-existing-iphone-and-ipad-app-ids-into-a-single-universal-app-id)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Legit question. if you downvote, don't hide behind it, explain it. This is why I've lost faith in StackOverflow being a good place to seek help.

Comment: There are at least two issues with your question: first of all, it is primarily opinion based. The other issue is that is is not about programming at all and not even slightly connected. This is purely about managing your apps, which questions belong to apple.stackexhange.com in case of iOS apps.

Comment: Then why do I find so many others with questions of this nature and no one with the same complaints as you had? It's not opinion based as I'm asking if there's a proper way that Apple wants us to handle this or if they have a way setup for us to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put out a final update on your existing apps, that puts up an alert explaining that there's now a universal app, and just leave your existing apps on the App Store.

Comment: I thought about that being a potential way to handle this as well. I wait a day for the possibility of a better response, before I mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you.