# Live iOS app: change bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning, cfbundleidentifier

I have an app on the app store that was deployed with a certificate for an app id with a wildcard bundle identifier. Now I have to add push notifications to this app, resulting in exactly the same problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575552/can-i-change-the-bundle-identifier-in-my-app-after-its-been-approved).

The answers in the linked question say I should create a new app id with the complete bundle identifier. This is a problem, as the provisioning portal is telling me "The bundle identifier you have specified is already in use. Please select another."

I have looked at all the app ids, provisioning profiles etc. and the bundle id is not in use. Either someone else is using it or I did it some long time ago and deleted it.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to contact Apple developer support. After some weeks they figured out that the bundle id was taken by another account and were able to transfer it to my account.